# In Terraforming Mars, do special tiles count as tiles you own when placing greenery tiles?

Tags: terraforming-mars

When placing a greenery tile in Terraforming Mars, you have to place it next to a tile you own. Let's say all you own is the "Mining Rights" tile and you are now playing a greenery tile. Do you have to play your greenery tile next to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

Special tiles have your player marker on them, so they are your tiles, just like greenery or city tiles.

From the rules, page 5:

> Special tiles: Some cards allow you to place
>   special tiles. Any function or placement
>   restriction is described on the card. Place the
>   tile, and **place a player marker on it**.

And

> Player markers: Each player uses his own color
>   to mark TR, **ownership of tiles**, production
>   (see page 6), and to indicate used blue card
>   actions (see page 11).

Comment: FWIW the only tiles that aren't owned are Ocean tiles.